# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) - cannot start server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Trying to feed a MySql database to AWS for a webapp I currently have running.  I haven't done this in a long time, but when I ssh'd into my AWS instance to feed the DB to my MySql server, I chose to run "sudo yum update" and it had 200+ updates.

I've tried starting/restarting my MySql server and get "FAILED" every time.

I've searched and do not have a /etc/mysql/my.cnf path, just /etc/my.cnf, and it contains:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

So I'm unsure where I'd plug in 127.0.0.1.

I've been searching for a solution for a couple hours now and have not found anything.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does log report say ?

Comment: If it's the log located here `/var/log/mysql/error.log` then it's empty unfortunately.